# Problem with JQuery .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

in the html i have an empty table tag.

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="0" id="TableID" class='TableOne'>
</table>
<input id="btn" value="test" type="button" />
```

in a jscript function, i'm adding some initial rows to the table, one of which contains another table.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += "\
    <tr>\
      <td>Row1\
        <table>\
          <tr>\
            <td></td>\
          </tr>\
        </table>\
      </td>\
    </tr>\
    <tr>\
      <td>Row2</td>\
    </tr>";
  $('#TableID').html(html);                   
  var newhtml = "<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>";
  $('#TableID').append(newhtml);
});
```

...

```
.tableOne
{
  border: 3px solid black;    
}
.tableTwo
{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

When this code is executed.... instead of seeing

Row1
Row2
Row3

we see

Row1
Row3
Row2

Row 3 is being put within the inner table.  Not the table I specified by id.... how can i fix this??

---

Edit:

I'm not sure what the cause of this actually is, but I found a work around.

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="0" class='tableOne'>
  <tbody id="TableID"></tbody>
</table>
<input id="btn" value="test" type="button" />
```

...

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += "\
    <tr>\
      <td>Row1\
        <table>\
          <tr>\
            <td></td>\
          </tr>\
        </table>\
      </td>\
    </tr>\
    <tr>\
      <td>Row2</td>\
    </tr>";
  $('#TableID').html(html);                   
  var newhtml = "<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>";
  $('#TableID').append(newhtml);
});
```

..

http://jsfiddle.net/sjord010/U88fa/3/

Comment: Do you close your initial `<table>` tag?

Comment: Whipped this up in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/bPwMg/, is the same problem occurring here? From what I can see, this is expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, I did close my initial table tag.  My code is actually alot more complex than that, that was a very simplified version. Never seen jsFiddle before, good tool.  But that is what should be happening... not's what is happening in my actual code.  I'll see what i can do to post some of the actual code here

Comment: I've added quite a bit of the actual code.  If there's something missing, let me know.

Comment: It seems like the only difference between my jsFiddle and your abbreviated example, then, is that I'm using two `$.append`s instead of one `$.append` and one `$.html`. Can you apply that to your actual case?

Comment: I modified your jsFiddle to use .html and it works there as well :-(  I'm working on modifying my code to it's simplest form and still recreating the problem.. maybe i'll find seomthing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjord010/U88fa/   simplified example that still has a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of the discussion in the comments, I think `$.html` just doesn't like when you pass it in malformed HTML. Regardless, here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/pjHsy/), and I just used `$.append` and cleaned up the whitespace a bit. Hope this helps. For posterity's sake, here's the relevant JS code:

```
var html = '';
html += "<tr><td><table class='tableTwo'><tr><td>Row1</td></tr></table></td></tr>";

html += "<tr><td><table class='tableTwo'><tr><td>Row2</td></tr></table></td></tr>";

$('#TableID').append(html);
newhtml = "<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>";
$('#TableID').append(newhtml);
```

Comment: Ah! I see!  Good to know for future reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out instead of append.

```
$('#TableID > tr:last').after(newhtml);
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/jquery-add-table-row/171049#171049) has a lot more information about this as well.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U88fa/4/).

Comment: This wont' work for me considering the last tr is technically the one that is contained within an inner table, so really it would cause the same issue.  I actually tried this.